# Is it possible to use spring cloud dataflow ui for commercial use if yes then how it is possible?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

and is there any way to deploy and modify existing code for stream-cloud-data flow UI alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Data Flow is covered by the liberal **Apache License, Version 2.0**. Therefore, yes, you can use the Spring Cloud Data Flow Dashboard (UI) commercially.

For more information, please see:

- https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_License